# Generic function to return a UITableViewCell subclass type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I've written an extension to easily dequeue table view cells of a certain type:

```
class RedCell:  UITableViewCell { }
class BlueCell: UITableViewCell { }

extension UITableView {
    func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>(_ type: T.Type, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
        let identifier = String(describing: T.self) // Must set on Storyboard
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! T
    }
}
```

This makes dequeuing cells of the correct type very easy:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(RedCell.self, for: indexPath) // type: RedCell
}
```

---

Now, rather than typing `RedCell.self` into that function call, I would like to store this `SomeCell.self` on a variable so that each of the enum cases can pass their own custom cell subclass to the table view:

```
enum Color {
    case red, blue

 // ...?
 // func cellType<T: UITableViewCell>() -> T.Type {
 // func cellType<T>() -> T.Type where T: UITableViewCell {
    func cellType<T>() -> T.Type {
        switch self {
        case .red:  return RedCell.self  // Cannot convert return expression of type 'RedCell.Type'  to return type 'T.Type'
        case .blue: return BlueCell.self // Cannot convert return expression of type 'BlueCell.Type' to return type 'T.Type'
        }
    }
    
}
```

Desired result is to construct the cell via the enum case:

```
let color = Color.red
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(color.cellType(), for: indexPath) // type: UITableViewCell
```

It's fine for the return type of the above call to be upcast to the in-common `UITableViewCell`, rather than a subclass. But the `cellType()` should dequeue the proper cell subclass from the Storyboard, as shown in the first code block, which is based on a String of the class name.

Is this possible? Xcode gives the errors above for my attempts to write the function.

What is the correct syntax for the generic function I'm attempting to write?

Comment: Do you need the function to be generic? Returning `UITableCell.Type` should work.

Comment: @Cristik That's true. Trying to make this more complicated than it is I guess. But aren't those generic functions essentially the same thing? Why don't they work?

Comment: Generics don't help you there, as even if the body of the method would compile, that method would force every caller to inject the `T` argument, which is not very helpful.

Comment: The compile problem comes from the fact that generic arguments in Swift are injected downstream, i.e. from the caller to the callee, thus the body of your method can't reconcile `T` with any of the `BlueCell`/`RedCell` types. Not even if you declare `T: UITableViewCell`.

Comment: What you are looking for is opaque return types, however those need polymorphic entities (protocols, classes), which won't work for your current design.

Comment: @Cristik returning a `UITableViewCell.Type` breaks my dequeue setup in the first code block. Searches for a cell with identifier `UITableViewCell`. :/

Comment: You might need some more work to do there, the enum is returning a concrete subclass of `UITableViewCell`, so you have access to the correct subclass, you just need to make sure it's properly propagated.

Answer (score 0):

No need for generics; just return `UITableViewCell.Type`:

```
enum Color {
    case red, blue

    func cellType() -> UITableViewCell.Type {
        switch self {
        case .red:  return RedCell.self
        case .blue: return BlueCell.self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It silent the compilation error. But you again need to specify type when you use dequeueReusableCell for accessing data members of the class.

Comment: In that case You can use protocol wrapper or force cast like as! RedCell

Comment: Then better to use direct function without enum

Comment: I thought this would work, but a `UITableViewCell.Type` return type in fact tries to dequeue `"UITableViewCell"` for all cases. Question updated to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I'm a fan of the idea but have a look at this, just use a private static variable and set it the desired type.

This way you avoid the inferring error from the return statement, and still change the type according to your enum case.

```
  enum Color {
   private static var cellType = UITableViewCell.self
   case red, blue

   private func setCellType(){
      switch self{
        case .red:
           Color.cellType = RedCell.self
        case .blue:
           Color.cellType = BlueCell.self
        }
    }


    func cellType<T: UITableViewCell>() -> T.Type {
        setCellType()
        return Color.cellType as! T.Type
       }

 }

class Test {
     init(){
       print(String(describing: Color.red.cellType()))
     }
}

let test = Test()
```